# Accessing instance variable after release

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management

This is a basic memory management code. I am dealing with an old app that does not have ARC implemented.

My question: Is it ok to access an instance variable after adding it to a view & releasing it.

In my opinion it is probably not right to access an instance variable after calling release on it, but can anyone advice ?

```
demoView = [[DemoView alloc] initWithFrame:[self demoRect:newType]];
[self addSubview:demoView]
[demoView release];
```

Later in code access it:

```
[demoView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
demoView.title = @"something";
```

object is released later on like this:

```
[demoView removeFromSuperview];
demoView = nil;
```

Comment: release demo view in dealloc

Answer (score 1):

When this line is called, the retainCount of demoView is 1.

```
demoView = [[DemoView alloc] initWithFrame:[self demoRect:newType]];
```

after this line

```
[self addSubview:demoView]
```

retainCount gets increased to 2.

If nothing else is done but the demoView is released later in dealloc, or just removed, it will still have a retainCount of 1. 
That is why the developer calls the

```
[demoView release];
```

to keep the retainCount at 1.

P.S. 
In the older retain/release paradigm, you would have to maintain the retainCount and keep that in check. retainCount gets increased on alloc, on getting added to a `UIView/NSArray/NSDictionary` and on calling `retain`
And retainCount decreases when you call release, remove from a `UIView/NSArray/NSDictionary`.

Comment: The object is not retained by any other object, it is released later on in the code by
[demoView removeFromSuperview];
demoView = nil;

Comment: "[C]hances are that developer is calling release to reduce `retainCount`." Note that the only valid reason to *ever* call `retain` is to reduce the retain count.

Comment: @Nash sorry, Read the code again and now it all makes sense. Let me know if you have any other confusion.

Comment: @Nash I take my words back, this isn't a bad programming practice, this is THE programming practice. Whenever people would add something to View, you would see them calling a release right after it.

Comment: The problem is that `demoView` is an ivar, and it should own the object it references (i.e., ensure the retain count is greater than zero) until `dealloc` is called. The only methods that should send `release` messages directly to ivars are setters and `dealloc`.

Comment: Any claims about absolute retain count are coincidental, at best.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a subview to a view, subview is retained by view.
So, if you use a subview after you release a subview, it will work. But it is a really bad practice to use some object you had already released.

Comment: So what I gather from all the answers here is that it is just bad practice, but there is nothing wrong in it and it will work.

Comment: It will work in most cases. It will fail if subview is removed from superview somewhere in code before you access it.

Answer (score 0):

It's generally best to use accessor methods rather than directly manipulating ivars in manually reference counted code. Consider rewriting the implementation along the following lines:

```
self.demoView = [[[DemoView alloc] initWithFrame:[self demoRect:newType]]
                autorelease]];

[self addSubview:demoView];
```

This way, if you remove the demo view from its superview you can safely keep it in memory should you ever want to add it back to the view hierarchy later, or move it to a different superview. In any case, the demo view should get a `release` message in `dealloc` so it can get cleaned up at the end of its owner's lifetime.